# FileMaker 17 API -- sort by recordId instead of fieldName

Tags: filemaker

I'm using curl to connect a FileMaker 17 database.

I can do a query and sort on a given fieldName, so for instance, I can do something like:

```
"sort":[
    {"fieldName": "Work State","sortOrder": "ascend"},
]
```

What I cannot do, but what I'd like to do is something like:

```
"sort":[
    {"fieldName": "recordId","sortOrder": "ascend"},
]
```

recordId is not a "field", and so the above does not work.  The syntax for this is not readily apparent in the FM documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, by saying that it's impossible to descend sort on a record ID within filemaker. Having to add another field is a workable solution, but in terms of the goal of documenting code in API it is not possible to descend sort on a record ID

Answer (score 1):

Not specifying any sort will sort by the creation order of the record, which matches what sorting by recordId would achieve. Adding a creation timestamp and sorting on that would make this explicit.

Comment: Not to be rude but adding a creation timestamp and sorting on that is sort of obvious right? I mean from your answer it sounds as if you cannot descend sort on a record ID

Comment: Seems you want to sort *descending*, that wasn't clear to me. Cheers!